# Redirecting IE 7 and IE 11 by useragent nginx config

Tags: nginx, internet-explorer-11, user-agent

I use nginx webserver and I'm trying to redirect old IE versions. I use MSIE tag for redirecting old version IE browsers ( 6,7,8,9,10). The code is:

```
if ($http_user_agent ~* '(MSIE 10.0|MSIE 9.0|MSIE 8.0|MSIE 7.0|MSIE 6.0)') {
    return 301 https://$host/some-url;
  }
```

But this also redirects the IE 11 browser. If I remove MSIE 7.0 then it doesn't redirect IE 11. So there is some conflict between both of them.

What I need to achieve is to redirect all older version if IE ( 6, 7, 8, 9 and 10) and allow only IE 11.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2013/09/21/internet-explorer-11s-many-user-agent-strings/ https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh869301%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Yes, I have already browsed the links. But that doesn't help me in this issue.

Comment: Find out why IE11 falls back to compatibility mode and sends IE7 UA. Also, make sure the redirect is not cached (and 301 would certainly be cached).

Comment: BTW, UA sniffing is considered a bad practice for an almost a decade…

Answer (score 4):

You can parse the `'rv:11'` in `$http_user_agent` to detect MSIE 11